# literal quotes entered into database by prepared statement contain preceding backslash

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to make a simple web interface for my database, and I'm using prepared statements  because they are supposed to prevent SQL injection attacks. Anyway, my problem is that if I enter single or double quotes in the form and submit it, then they are entered into the database preceded by a backslash, which is also printed out with them when the items are selected from the database.

So, how do I enter a literal quote into the database without it aquiring a preceding backslash due to the prepare statement? Cheers.

```
<?php

$heading = $_POST['heading'];
$story = $_POST['story'];

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost',$username,$password,'mydb');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
  echo "Failed to connect: Error (".$mysqli->connect_errno.") ".$mysqli->connect_error;

if (  !$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO news (heading,story) VALUES (?,?)')  )
  echo "Prepare failed: Error (".$mysqli->errno.") ".$mysqli->error;

if (  !$stmt->bind_param('ss',$heading,$story)  )
  echo "Binding paramaters failed: (".$stmt->errno.") ".$stmt->error;

if (!$stmt->execute())
  echo "Execute failed: (".$stmt->errno.") ".$stmt->error;

$stmt->close();

?>
```

Comment: Do you have magic_quotes turned on or off in php.ini?

Comment: THANKYOU!! That was it! I set "magic_quotes_gpc" to "Off", restarted Apache, and now no additional escaping is taking place. I thought the prepared statements must have been escaping the special characters twice or something. I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I guess I should have said that as an Answer, lol =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure magic_quotes is turned off in php.ini.

Comment: i use stripslashes function on all my input if get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using any native PHP functions like mysql_real_escape_string() or addslashes()?

These functions will natively escape potentially hazardous strings from being inserted.

Comment: http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php is the best way to go in my personal opinion.

Comment: Neither of these functions work well with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Use `htmlspecialchars()` to convert special characters to HTML entities or `mysql_escape_string()` to escape all «strange» symbols

Comment: This is the correct solution. Then simply use their equivalent reversing functions when displaying the result.

Comment: mysql_escape_string() is DEPRECATED. Do some research before you vote down answers in lieu of your own incorrect ones.

Comment: @BarryChapman Why do You think that I have voted down Your answer?

Comment: It was me Barry, although in the same breath I decidedit didn't deserve a down-vote and removed it.

Comment: @BarryChapman for `mysql_real_escape_string()` connection before it calls is required, I really don't know when @linitbuff will prepare his data to insert, so I use `mysql_escape_string()` in my answer